# Grant Select on a view not base table when base table is in a different database

Tags: sql-server

I have a view which is selecting rows from a table in a different database.  I'd like to grant select access to the view, but not direct access to the base table.  The view has a where clause restricting the number of rows.

Can I grant select to the view and not the base table, or do I need to switch to a stored procedure? I would rather not do it the latter way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you state in one of your comments that the table in question is in a different database, then [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) applies. I suspect there is a break in the chain somewhere - check that link for full details.

Answer (score 19):

```
GRANT SELECT ON [viewname] TO [user]
```

should do it.

Comment: Actually, the user doesn't have access to the base table referred to in the view, so I get an error stating I don't have access in the current security context.

Comment: @Jiyosub: I just needed to add a login for the server and a user for the database. I didn't add any memberships or set them owner of anything. When I ran the GRANT permissions above to that user I could log in as the user and see the views but not the tables from SSMS.

Answer (score 19):

I also had this problem. I used information from link, mentioned above, and found quick solution. If you have different schema, lets say **test**, and create user **utest**, owner of schema **test** and among views in schema **test** you have view **vTestView**, based on tables from schema **dbo**, while selecting from it you'll get error mentioned above - no access to base objects. It was enough for me to execute statement

`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON test.vTestView TO dbo`;

which means that I change an ownership of **vTextView** from schema it belongs to (**test**) to database user **dbo**, owner of schema **dbo**. After that without any other permissions required user **utest** will be able to access data from **test.vTestView**

Comment: What if I don't want to change ownership of objects, I just want to provide permission? I tried granting schema permissions to dbo but it fails (it already has permission).

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are partily correct, you are able to use [GRANT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) to only grant permission to a view without granting permission to its base table.

But since it is cross-db, you also need enable Cross Database Ownership Chain at instance level.
[image: Corss Database Ownership Chaining]

You also need to make sure the view and the base table are owned by the same owner or the ownership chain won't work. In modern versions of SQL Server (maybe after SQL Server 2003), all tables and views are owned by its schema by default so it actually means the owner of the schema should also be same. By default, the schema of every user table is "dbo", which means "database owner", so the database owner of the two related DB should be same.

[image: DB Owner]

You can read these two articles to know more about SQL Server Ownership Chainingand Cross Database Owernship Chaining.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6394/understanding-sql-server-ownership-chaining/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1782/understanding-cross-database-ownership-chaining-in-sql-server/

And maybe you also want to know more about SQL Server logins and database users, since for the user who you want to grant access to the view only in DB A, you do need to give him at least "public" role in the DB which your base table resides: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can grant permissions on a view and not the base table.  This is one of the reasons people like using views.

Have a look here: [GRANT Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: Because the user doesn't have access to the base table the view is referring to, even though I grant select privilege to the view, I still get select permission was denied to the base table.  I don't want to grant direct privileges on the base table.

Comment: I tested this under SQL Server 2005.  You grant the user public on the database then permissions on the view.  In testing this, the user does not have select on the table and can select from the view.  The user cannot even see the tables in the UI.

Comment: Hmmm, 2 things differ in my setup.  SQL 2008 and the view is referencing a table in another database.  However, the database is on the same server and the user has public on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in one of my databases.

To get it to work, the user had to be added to the database housing the actual data.  No rights were needed, just access.

Have you considered keeping the view in the database it references?  Re usability and all if its benefits could follow.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was getting the same error message for a user. I feel that by sharing my mistake, I can clear up the issue, answer the question, and prevent others from making the same mistake. 
I wanted a user to have access to 4 particular views without having access to their underlying tables (or anything else in the DB for that matter). 
Initially I gave them the database role membership of "db_denydatareader" thinking that this would prevent them from selecting anything from any table or view (which it did - as I thought), though I then granted "select" on these 4 views assuming that it would work as I intended - it did not. 
The correct way to do it is to simply *not* grant them the db_datareader role and simply grant "select" on the items which you want the user to be able to access. The results of the above was that the user was able to access absolutely nothing outside these 4 views - the tables which these views area based on are also not available to this user.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem.  It appears that although permission to "View1" as part of schema "schema1" needs to be granted by the owner "dbo" if View1 uses dbo.table1.

Unless a schema gets used which is not part of dbo then this problem may not become apparent, and the regular solution of "Grant Select to user" would work.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this is to give the user permission to the tables that I didn't want them to have access to. Then fine tune the select permission in SSMS by only allowing select permission to the columns that are in my view. This way, the select clause on the table is only limited to the columns that they see in the view anyways.

[image]

Shaji

Answer (score 0):

`Create view Schema1.viewName1 as (select * from plaplapla)`

`Schema1` has all the tables

`Create view Schema2.viewName2 as (select * from schema1.viewName1)`

`schema2` has no tables(only views schema)

In this case you can execute (`select * from viewName2`) in schema2 , BUT .. If you `deleted viewNmae1 from Schema1` , Then `ViewName2` will not work..

Amani El Gamal 
aljamalaisj81@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

Just have a materialized view then you don't have to worry about all other factors. This is only going to work if space and refresh time is not a big deal.. materialized views are pretty cool.

Comment: The base table is in a different database. He cannot use materialized view. IMO materialized views in SQL Server are not cool at all.