# Grant SELECT permission on a view, but not on underlying objects

Tags: sql, security, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I often read that one purpose of a VIEW is security: to allow some users access to the underlying table, and other users to a derived view only. With that in mind I designed several views that supply restricted datasets to external users.

All very fine, but in practice this doesn't work. After I grant `SELECT` permission on a view, the users can't access it unless I grant `SELECT` on all underlying objects too. Same story for stored procedures. The net result is non-functional, for I end up still granting access to sensitive data to the wrong users, as well as annoying, for it is easy to forget one object and the users come back to complain that the view "doesn't work".

Is there a way to grant `SELECT` permissions on a view or stored procedure without having to expose the underlying objects too?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368414/grant-select-on-a-view-not-base-table

Comment: Yes, at first I thought that wasn't my problem. But it is ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does the same user who owns the view also own the underlying tables? If not, the owner of the tables needs to grant the view owner permission WITH GRANT OPTION. If the same user owns both the tables and the view, then granting permission on the view should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what's going on. I have two databases, and problems arise only if I incorporate references to the other database in a view defined in one database. It has to do with ownership.

Comment: By granting WITH GRANT though when the owners are different, we are giving permissions to do more than just select - is this the only way to get it to work in such situations (without granting access to the underlying objects)?

Answer (score 3):

You might find the information in [this forum](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic751807-359-1.aspx#bm752442) helpful.

The last post has the details of what was run to grant permissions to a view but not the underlying tables:

```
CREATE USER [Reports] FOR LOGIN [Reports] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Reports
CREATE SCHEMA Reports AUTHORIZATION Reports --Auth as Reports was the key piece of information that I had missed.
GO
CREATE ROLE Reporting AUTHORIZATION db_securityadmin
GO
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'Reporting', @membername = 'Reports'
GO
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO Reporting
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO Reporting

GRANT SELECT, VIEW DEFINITION ON [dbo].[zName] TO Reporting;
```

FYI - For stored procedures, you should be granting EXEC to the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your views in a different schema than the table, you must either grant the user access to the base table, "AUTHORIZE" the owner of the tables to the view like this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON reporting.MyViewName TO dbo
```

In the example above `dbo` is the user owning the tables the `reporting.MyViewName` is accessing