# Do I need permissions for underlying tables when querying a view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

If I have the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Sample]
AS
    SELECT  T1.Column1, 
            T1.Column2,
            Table2.Column1, 
            Table2.Column2
    FROM dbo.Table1 T1
    JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T2.Column3 = T1.Column3
GO
```

And I want to grant a user access to `SELECT` from that view; do I need to either:

A - Give that user `SELECT` permissions on just the view:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[vw_Sample] TO [MyUser]
```

**or**

B - Give that user `SELECT` permissions on view and underlying tables:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[Table1] TO [MyUser]
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[Table2] TO [MyUser]
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[vw_Sample] TO [MyUser]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the View (A). Granting Select on the underlying tables will give them more access than they may need. The link below has some helpful info on ownership of the view\table and the affects it may have on your access.

[Grant SELECT permission on a view, but not on underlying objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134740/grant-select-permission-on-a-view-but-not-on-underlying-objects)

Answer (score 0):

B. Each object you created (view, procedure or function) will be execute under caller permissions. So, trying to select from underlying tables without necessary permissions will cause permission error. Or you may use EXECUTE AS/SET USER statements: please refer to TechNet article: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188268(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188268%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)