# Cross db permission issue

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 databases on the same SQL Server 2012:
 - erpCountry1
 - erpCountry2
 - erpWeb

erpWeb database was built to allow a special user (webUser) to read some data from outside. It is mostly a few views like this (simplified version):

```
create view erpWeb.dbo.vwClients
as
SELECT 'XX' as Region, IdClient, Nom, Adress
    FROM erpCountry1.dbo.Clients
UNION ALL
SELECT 'YY' as Region, IdClient, Nom, Adress
    FROM erpCountry2.dbo.Clients
```

Currently the user webUser must be mapped to `erpCountry1` and `erpCountry2` databases, otherwise view `erpWeb.dbo.vwClients` does not work for him.

My question is: what should I do to allow webUser to see the result of vwClients WITHOUT mapping webUser as `datareader` for erpCountry1 and erpCountry2 ? (since this allows webUser to see all data of those databases)

**Edit**: in Access, you can define a query to run with owner's permissions (instead of user's). Isn't there anything equivalent in SQL Server ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this `result of vwClients WITHOUT allowing webUser to see the contents`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134740/grant-select-permission-on-a-view-but-not-on-underlying-objects

Comment: @TheGameiswar I edited the last paragraph

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus same question indeed...but I don't really understand how to implement this `with grant option`

Comment: I could be wrong, but you may need to either mark Web DB as `trustworthy` or set up certificate access. Did that a long time ago so take this with a grain of salt.