# SQL user access needed for views

Tags: sql-server

I am working in MS SQL Server 2014.  I have to send data from a certain DB (call it "DB_old") to an external application.  This application reads data from DB_old via a connection that is built with a certain SQL service account.  I just discovered that certain columns in tables from DB_old are not allowed to be loaded into this external application.  So:
1) I removed this SQL service account's access to DB_old;
2) I created a new DB (call it "DB_new") and views on DB_new that select the permissible columns from DB_old;
3) I granted the SQL service account access to all views on DB_new

I thought that the above would resolve my data exposure problem.  However, when I log into SSMS with the given SQL service account (which is successful) and try to run some simple SELECTs against the views on DB_new, I get the following error:

> The server principal "SQL_service_account" is not able to access the database "DB_old" under the current security context.

I am not sure how to resolve this seeming ownership chain problem.  To be clear, I am the owner of DB_new and all schemas underneath it, but I am not the owner of DB_old or any schemas underneath it.  And, I cannot allow SQL_service_account to select any tables under DB_old.  And, I cannot build my views on DB_old.  They have to be built on DB_new.

What is the best way to resolve this ownership chain problem?

Comment: You need to give a user access to data but you can't give the user access to the table? I think you answered your own question...

Comment: Right.  That is why I created the views.  But, the user can't select any data from the views.  I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134740/grant-select-permission-on-a-view-but-not-on-underlying-objects

Comment: Actually, I looked at that post (and the post it references) before I submitted my question.  I'm not entirely sure what either post is saying.  I think it's saying to have the owner of the DB_old tables grant me (the create of the views on DB_new) the WITH GRANT OPTION when I get access to the tables, so that I can grant the same access to user SQL_service_account.  But, that defeats the purpose.  I can't allow SQL_service_account to access the underyling tables.