# Updating views with VBA-ADO in SQL Server requires UPDATE privileges on underlying table (MS Access / VBA)

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ado, adodb

I have a problem updating views with ADO in MS Access.

I created views for my tables, they contain columns and rows that are eligable to be changed. For example, the table `tbl_tablename` will have the view: `vw_tablename_editable` with some `WHERE` clauses to determine wether the the rows should be editable or not.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_tablename_editable 
AS 
    SELECT tablename_id, tablename_fieldtoupdate 
    FROM dbo.tbl_tablename 
    WHERE table_criteriafield > 1000 -- 1000 being some criteria
```

The permissions work: when I run `UPDATE` queries on the view as a user with only `UPDATE` permissions on the view, the information is correctly updated. Also when using DAO linked tables in Access, I can view and modify the data.

The problem is when I am using ADO and try to update the views, both using the Bound controls and manual updating in VBA.

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        
    With rs
        Set .ActiveConnection = connectionstr            
        .source = "SELECT tablename_id, tablename_fieldtoupdate FROM vw_tablename_editable " & _ 
        "WHERE tablename_id = " & id_ofrecordtobeupdated
        .cursortype = adOpenStatic
        .cursorlocation = adUseClient
        .locktype = adLockOptimistic
       .Open
   End With 

rs!tablename_fieldtoupdate = "new value"

rs.update
```

The error message I am getting is:

> The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'tbl_tablename', database 'mydatabase', schema 'dbo'

[It seems to be related with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134740/grant-select-permission-on-a-view-but-not-on-underlying-objects), however, the SELECT statements in ADO just fine without giving the user access to the underlying tables.

The problem is solved when I give the users direct UPDATE access to the tables or the DBO schema, but I would like to avoid this. When logged in as DBO updating works both with the MS Access bound controls and the manual VBA way.

I also tried to make an indexed view, but this also does not seem to make a difference.

Edit

By suggestion of user @wqw inserting WITH VIEW_METADATA, it now works perfectly!

```
CREATE VIEW vw_tablename_editable 
WITH VIEW_METADATA
AS 
    SELECT tablename_id, tablename_fieldtoupdate 
    FROM dbo.tbl_tablename 
    WHERE table_criteriafield > 1000 -- 1000 being some criteria
```

Comment: Slight detour...but an extremely important one....you need to read about, understand and start parameterizing your queries. What you have is the classic example of sql injection.

Comment: Think about this for a second. A view is just a stored query against one or more tables. If you update the view it really means you are updating the underlying table(s). If a user is not allowed to update the table, why should they be allowed to update the view?

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, I am aware of SQL injection, none of the SQL statements are from userinput. I did not know about paramametized queries! I found this: https://evona.nl/simple-parameterized-queries-using-ado-in-vba/ and will incoperate it in my project!

Comment: @SeanLange Yes that would make sense, this was my thought as well. The weird thing is though, that just selecting the records works with ADO works, without SELECT permission on the table: the records are loading correctly. Also updating with regular query works for the users with only UPDATE + SELECT permissions on the view, even if they dont have those permissions on the table.   When loading the views into acces as linked table, a user with SELECT+UPDATE on only the view is able to see and update the records. Only when trying to update the view with ADO Recordsets it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create your views using WITH VIEW_METADATA option which is generally harmless for anything T-SQL related (e.g. queries or stored procedures) but instructs OLEDB/ADO (and other data-access connectors like ODBC) to update through view's columns and not the (several) base tables.

Answer (score 0):

[Ownership chains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-ownership-chains-and-context-switching?view=sql-server-ver16) will suppress permissions checks on tables when any DML is executed on a view owned by the same user.  Apparently ADO is discovering the underlying table and accessing it directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am not sure what you mean on the first part, but regarding the second part: I ran the profiler and as you predicted, it tries to run a `UPDATE` command on the table instead of the view. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: thanks for the edit. I am using the ADO to bind the recordsets to the forms, so I would not have to code an update query for every field in each form. But I guess I just hit a limitation of ADO :(

Comment: @Daniel technically, in SQL server you cannot update a view. Views are just stored queries. Like a picture of a real thing. Updating a picture wouldn't update the thing. ADO does some nice stuff by finding the underlying table for you, but that abstraction isn't obvious initially.