# grant read access on a view but not on it's underlying tables from other databases

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, schema

I want to grant read permissions for a user for a view which joins 2 tables from another database.
**I don't** want to:

1. give him permission on the database where the tables are or add him as an user there.
2. Make him the owner of the view/schema due to the security exploits.
3. I don't want to create first a table, or variations of a hack table with a `truncate` and a stored procedure which inserts the data on a trigger.

Can this be done somehow? Maybe there's something I missed and you guys might know.

I have read these posts but they didn't solve my problem:
[Grant SELECT permission on a view, but not on underlying objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134740/grant-select-permission-on-a-view-but-not-on-underlying-objects)

[Grant Select on a view not base table when base table is in a different database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368414/grant-select-on-a-view-not-base-table-when-base-table-is-in-a-different-database)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89632/sql-server-grant-select-access-to-a-user-in-a-view-and-not-in-its-tables

Thank you

**Edit:**
The easiest solution I came up with, after some research, is activating the `cross database ownership chaining`option on the database where I'm placing the views and granting the read permission to the users. This might be in contrast with my 2nd point of things I'm trying to avoid. Is this a good idea?

Comment: I have got same situation in my practice. I don't know how you will deliver data from view to user - we used web page, that was connecting to DB under SQL Server login, which has only read access to the view and all tables involved. Access to view the page was controlled by IIS server which ask for windows authentication (AD).

Comment: The user will use an excel to connect directly to the db. Do you know a way without using any webpage or another software other than sql server management studio?

Comment: Unfortunately, at first I was thinking about Excel as a tool to deliver that data, but haven't find any sufficient secure way to make it. Here comes decision to provide it via IIS server I have been running. I think you can look at SSRS, personally I haven't use it but my colleagues do - and it might be a solution for your problem. You can make a report that users can view, but they will have no way to get/change data via this report.

Comment: CM2K one way around it would be to put the view on a separate server via a linked server and give them SELECT permissions on that view.

Comment: Your first point in the enumerated list makes this difficult. In order to check permissions, the database needs a principal to check against. If you don't add the user into the target database, there's nothing to check against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

1. Create an active directory group.
2. Add users to the AD group.
3. Create a login for the AD group mapped for the source DB and target DB.
4. Add the user on the target DB and give him permissions only for the requested views.
5. (Optional) Added the group on all the databases to deny select.

Couldn't find a solution for my original question without the AD group.

Answer (score 1):

Give them a login to another database on the same server, and include only your single view, with the view pointing to your secure database. Don't give that login any access to anything but the database with the view in it, and only read access to that single view.  Obviously, you'll have to fully qualify your table name (e.g., `from SourceDB.dbo.SomeSecretTable`).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this is exactly what I did and the user couldn't access the view because he was lacking permissions on the database where the tables were. The table name was fully qualified. Please see my edit. I think this will work if I will also enable the `cross database ownership chaining`. But is this a good idea?

Comment: Hmm.  Microsoft recommends against chaining ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669059.aspx ).  Tell me this: do they know the database name of the other, secret database?  If they don't, they'd have no way of knowing they had select access to it, so you wouldn't lose anything by granting that same login select access to the secret db.  That would get around the ownership chaining issue, and still accomplish what you're looking to do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure some might know the name of the database. So this won't be a good approach

Comment: Check out the answer from Kosmo, on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368414/ , and see if that might address it? It simplifies things immensely, as you'd be creating a separate schema for that user & then creating the view within that schema, not granting them view access to dbo schema.  Worth a try anyway?

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks. This post slowly transforms in a wiki :)

Comment: Indeed.  When you think you've got the optimal solution, do post it, as I really think it's something other people will encounter.  If you can't turn it into a community wiki, I think I can.

Comment: I had other things I had to work on. But at a first glance, after trying to transfer the ownership as suggested on the post you provided..well it didn't work. Maybe I missed something. I'll keep on trying once I get a little  time and once I'll find a solution, will post it here.